# Filter topic across multiple contracts

Tags: contract-design, events, filters

Is there something I could add to my contract which allows my application to filter for all the deployed contracts which also included this topic/identifier?

The only other option to manage this I can think of would be to deploy a "manager" contract which stores a list of all other contracts (and every new contract by my application would send their address to it).

What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how 'decentralized' you want your application to be. If you want to decentralize all data, you'll have to go with the manager contract or something similiar.

If you can store the data on a central server, you should probably do that.